# Overwrite Twitter Bootstrap 3's radio group "onclick" event

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

I basically created an on/off switch using twitter bootstrap's Button Group component using two radio buttons.

The problem is when I click an "active" (or "checked") radio button I want the switch to trigger a change anyway. I can do this via Javascript, but for some reason it automatically clicks back after my JS completes.

So essentially I click, my JS clicks the other label, then Bootsrap clicks it back. Anyway to overwrite Bootstraps behavior?

**[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2okLge8n/1/)**

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group sp_toggle_switch" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
        <input type="radio" name="display_share_btn" value="true">ON
    </label>      
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <input type="radio" name="display_share_btn" value="false">OFF
    </label>      
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).on('click','.sp_toggle_switch label.active',function(){
  $(this).siblings('label:not(.active)').trigger('click');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.sp_toggle_switch label:not(.active ) {background:#ffffff;  border-color: #ccc;}
.sp_toggle_switch label:not(.active ):hover {background:#f1f1f1;}
.sp_toggle_switch label {text-indent: 99px; overflow: hidden; width: 30px;}
.sp_toggle_switch label.active {text-indent: 0px; width: 36px;}
.sp_toggle_switch.switch_sm label {width: 24px; height: 17px; font-size: 10px; line-height: 14px;}
.sp_toggle_switch.switch_sm label.active {width: 32px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow...I was determined to figure this one out for some reason.  I worked on it a bit yesterday with no luck, but I think I mastered it this morning. I have it working in my environment, so hopefully it works for you

```
$('.sp_toggle_switch label').on('click',function(e){

    var parent = $(this).closest('[data-toggle="buttons"]');

    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {

        $(this).find('input:radio').removeAttr('checked');

        parent.find('label').not('.active').find('input:radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
        parent.find('label').not('.active').addClass('active');  

        $(this).removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault(); // to prevent bootstrap from triggering after class change
        return false;

    } else {

        $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
        parent.find('.active').find('input:radio').removeAttr('checked');

        return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: Well technically this worked. Well played! Thank you so much for your time! Now I think I found a cleaner solution, but this was only after your code inspired me. I just set "return false" after my JS click and it stops further code from executing. Seems to work. Again this came from seeing what you wrote. I'll update my question with the answer.

Comment: Glad I could inspire you, @DigitalMC!  It was definitely a fun challenge.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want the switch to toggle regardless of where it's clicked? If so, this is kind of lazy, but will probably work:

```
$(document).on('click','.sp_toggle_switch label.active',function(e){
    var inactive = $(this).siblings('label').not('.active');
    setTimeout(function() {
        inactive.trigger('click');
    }, 100);
});
```

I know it doesn't answer your question about disabling the default behavior, but I'm not sure it's wise to mess with that, anyway. This gets you what I think you want in a way that's most likely seamless to the user, though admittedly, a little ugly.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, anywhere I click I want to toggle. I was considering a timeout or a setInterval (would be more bulletproof) but trying to avoid it if possible. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add "return false" after the JS click and it will stop further JS from executing.

```
$(document).on('click','.sp_toggle_switch label.active',function(){
    $(this).siblings('label:not(.active)').trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

[Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2okLge8n/2/)